# Screen navigates to previous screen automatically in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

So, in my root `index.js` file I've this route

```
const RootNav = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: {
        screen: Auth
    },
    Tabs: {
        screen: TabHolder
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
  }
);
```

**Auth.js**

```
const Auth = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Splash: {
          screen:Splash
      },
      BeforeLogin: {
          screen:BeforeLogin
      },    
      Signin: {
          screen:Signin,
      },
      ForgotPassword: {
          screen:ForgotPassword
      },
      Signup: {
          screen:Signup
      },
    },
    {
        headerMode:'none',
        mode:'modal', 
    }
  );
```

**TabHolder.js**

```
const TabHolder = createBottomTabNavigator ({
 HomeMainTab: {
      screen: HomeMainStack,
      navigationOptions: { },
},
 ProfileMainTab: {
      screen: ProfileMainStack,
      navigationOptions: { },
},
)}

const ProfileMainStack = createStackNavigator({

      Profile: {
          screen:Profile
      },
      Settings: {
          screen:Settings,
      },
    },
  {
      headerMode:'none',
      mode:'modal',
  },
);
```

Now when I navigate from `Settings` screen to `Signin` screen using `this.props.navigation.navigate('Signin')`. I get navigated to `Signin` screen and then immediately to `BeforeLogin` screen. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Is there something in the Signin screen that would redirect to the BeforeLogin screen?

Comment: @FrankerZ No. There is no BeforeLogin navigation in Signin screen

Comment: try to change swap order of definition of  BeforeLogin and Signin

Comment: @DhavalkumarPrajapati Tried. Didn't work

Comment: then please share code of you signin screen may you wrote redirection there !

Comment: @DhavalkumarPrajapati  please check this. It has my `Signin.js` and `BeforeLogin.js` file https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/546a8c9b30d840bab8dddedc14376832